# Lude composition of the matrix question about theory

Tags: linear-algebra

In the lude composition of matrix sometimes they have it like

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\ x & 1 & 0\\ y & z & 1\end{bmatrix} \times \begin{bmatrix} a & b & c\\ 0 & d & e\\ 0 & 0 & f\end{bmatrix}$$

And sometimes they have the composition like

$$ \begin{bmatrix} x& 0 & 0\\ y & z & 0\\ w & v & u\end{bmatrix} \times \begin{bmatrix} 1 & a & b\\ 0 & 1 & c\\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

Is it something like mistake or correct composition?

You see my question is about the position of 1s in the composition.  Thanks!

Comment: Either way is technically correct in the sense that it is a decomposition into a lower triangular and an upper triangular matrix in a product. The former way is usually preferred because it doesn't use any row-rescaling operations. Of course in real practice you usually would have a $PA=LU$ decomposition instead, except in the positive definite case.